# Forming a saliency map from a CSV that contains gaze fixation data

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, pytorch, heatmap

I have a CSV file containing gaze fixations for participants in a study that have been given an image to observe. One of the columns in the CSV file contains an array of data in the format of:

[[581,497,23,0,720,899],[666,539,56,0,720,899],[616,500,83,0,720,899]]

Where the data in the nested array gives us information about where the participant was looking. For example, if the array was:

`[933,47,365,0,1073,725]`

The array would be telling us that:

- The participant was looking around the "933 x 47" pixels on their screen
- They were looking there at 365ms from the start of the study
- "0" means the image has not been scrolled
- The participant's mouse was at the pixel location of "1073 x 725"

The site I used for collecting the gaze fixations provided a final heatmap for the participant's gaze, however, I need to extract just the heat map and make it grayscale so that I can compare it with the saliency map of a saliency model.

[image]

An image of the heatmap provided by the site forms a heat map from the viewer's gaze fixations.

[image]

An example of what I want to do with the CSV data

I have attempted to form the heatmap myself using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

# Define the input image size
img_size = (1024, 1280)

# Create an empty numpy array of the same size as the input image
saliency_map = np.zeros(img_size)

array1 = [[581,497,23,0,720,899],[666,539,56,0,720,899],[616,500,83,0,720,899],[639,490,110,0,720,899],[658,511,143,0,720,899],[671,514,173,0,720,899],[671,514,199,0,720,899],[662,511,236,0,720,899],[614,489,261,0,720,899],[641,480,291,0,720,899],[664,479,331,0,720,899],[665,485,357,0,720,899],[667,508,389,0,720,899],[681,488,425,0,720,899],[696,491,451,0,720,899],[652,499,485,0,720,899],[717,509,523,0,720,899],[675,477,555,0,720,899],[737,494,579,0,720,899],[751,482,613,0,720,899],[714,469,647,0,720,899],[753,470,675,0,720,899],[761,467,707,0,720,899],[715,488,740,0,720,899],[695,475,779,0,720,899],[716,480,804,0,720,899],[702,473,840,0,720,899],[702,473,866,0,720,899],[698,469,900,0,720,899],[706,476,935,0,720,899],[772,468,963,0,720,899],[723,471,997,0,720,899],[704,469,1034,0,720,899],[733,471,1064,0,720,899],[719,461,1090,0,720,899],[678,458,1122,0,720,899],[724,449,1160,0,720,899],[695,438,1186,0,720,899],[636,483,1217,0,720,899],[657,502,1254,0,720,899],[717,481,1289,0,720,899],[688,499,1317,0,720,899],[632,496,1345,0,720,899],[556,453,1383,0,720,899],[489,492,1410,0,720,899],[470,493,1443,0,720,899],[428,481,1480,0,720,899],[428,491,1519,0,720,899],[352,483,1537,0,720,899],[328,489,1573,0,720,899],[341,503,1610,0,720,899],[338,535,1636,0,720,899],[338,535,1667,0,720,899],[341,527,1706,0,720,899],[358,550,1733,0,720,899],[330,487,1765,0,720,899],[365,475,1803,0,720,899],[400,462,1830,0,720,899],[1153,602,1861,0,720,899],[1118,605,1896,0,720,899],[1123,600,1925,0,720,899],[1190,540,1958,0,720,899],[1171,526,1985,0,720,899],[1180,534,2017,0,720,899],[1033,473,2044,0,720,899],[983,477,2079,0,720,899],[1002,494,2109,0,720,899],[917,488,2139,0,720,899],[917,488,2165,0,720,899],[961,483,2197,0,720,899],[897,483,2235,0,720,899],[884,498,2259,0,720,899],[826,492,2291,0,720,899],[792,483,2324,0,720,899],[774,468,2363,0,720,899],[850,469,2393,0,720,899],[803,446,2421,0,720,899],[698,426,2454,0,720,899],[701,427,2488,0,720,899],[708,449,2521,0,720,899],[672,424,2559,0,720,899],[647,439,2583,0,720,899],[616,435,2616,0,720,899],[630,438,2642,0,720,899],[664,428,2676,0,720,899],[632,428,2714,0,720,899],[664,434,2741,0,720,899],[658,428,2772,0,720,899],[658,428,2800,0,720,899],[709,423,2834,0,720,899],[709,423,2870,0,720,899],[723,405,2897,0,720,899],[660,408,2936,0,720,899],[646,414,2959,0,720,899],[619,429,2997,0,720,899]]
combined_array = np.array(array1)

# Loop through the combined array and draw circles on the empty array
for i in range(len(combined_array)):
    x, y, duration, _, _, _ = combined_array[i]
    radius = int(duration / 80)  # Adjust the radius based on the duration
    brightness = duration / 100  # Adjust the brightness based on the duration
    saliency_map = cv2.circle(saliency_map, (x, y), radius, brightness, -1)

# Apply a Gaussian blur to the resulting array
saliency_map = cv2.GaussianBlur(saliency_map, (0, 0), sigmaX=40, sigmaY=40)

# Plot the resulting array
plt.imshow(saliency_map, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Output for my code. This doesn't look like I've done it correctly as the centre point in the original heat map is much bigger, and also the leftmost point is right next to the image border.

If anyone could give me any tips on how to modify my code so that it looks more like to original (but just grayscale without the background image) that would be greatly appreciated.

And if I am going in the completely wrong direction to form the saliency map then please let me know of that as well.

Many thanks for anyone that takes the time to answer.

Comment: please review [mre]. present consistent data. the first answer given below indicates that you did not.

Answer (score 0):

So, I was trying to get your data to line up with your image so I had a reference point for how well I was doing, but I think it's possible that this is the tracking data for a different image. Take a look:

[image: attempt_1]

This looks a little different to me than the fixation locations on the original image, is this the data for the same image? I subtracted some of the values of the coordinates to try to line it up. I got rid of the blur to try and see the locations a little better for a second.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

# Pull in gaze_fixation.png and get the dimensions
img = cv2.imread('gaze_fixation.png')
height, width, channels = img.shape
print("dimensions: ", width, height)

# Define the input image size
img_size = (height, width)

# Create an empty numpy array of the same size as the input image
saliency_map = np.zeros(img_size)

array1 = [[581,497,23,0,720,899],[666,539,56,0,720,899],[616,500,83,0,720,899],[639,490,110,0,720,899],[658,511,143,0,720,899],[671,514,173,0,720,899],[671,514,199,0,720,899],[662,511,236,0,720,899],[614,489,261,0,720,899],[641,480,291,0,720,899],[664,479,331,0,720,899],[665,485,357,0,720,899],[667,508,389,0,720,899],[681,488,425,0,720,899],[696,491,451,0,720,899],[652,499,485,0,720,899],[717,509,523,0,720,899],[675,477,555,0,720,899],[737,494,579,0,720,899],[751,482,613,0,720,899],[714,469,647,0,720,899],[753,470,675,0,720,899],[761,467,707,0,720,899],[715,488,740,0,720,899],[695,475,779,0,720,899],[716,480,804,0,720,899],[702,473,840,0,720,899],[702,473,866,0,720,899],[698,469,900,0,720,899],[706,476,935,0,720,899],[772,468,963,0,720,899],[723,471,997,0,720,899],[704,469,1034,0,720,899],[733,471,1064,0,720,899],[719,461,1090,0,720,899],[678,458,1122,0,720,899],[724,449,1160,0,720,899],[695,438,1186,0,720,899],[636,483,1217,0,720,899],[657,502,1254,0,720,899],[717,481,1289,0,720,899],[688,499,1317,0,720,899],[632,496,1345,0,720,899],[556,453,1383,0,720,899],[489,492,1410,0,720,899],[470,493,1443,0,720,899],[428,481,1480,0,720,899],[428,491,1519,0,720,899],[352,483,1537,0,720,899],[328,489,1573,0,720,899],[341,503,1610,0,720,899],[338,535,1636,0,720,899],[338,535,1667,0,720,899],[341,527,1706,0,720,899],[358,550,1733,0,720,899],[330,487,1765,0,720,899],[365,475,1803,0,720,899],[400,462,1830,0,720,899],[1153,602,1861,0,720,899],[1118,605,1896,0,720,899],[1123,600,1925,0,720,899],[1190,540,1958,0,720,899],[1171,526,1985,0,720,899],[1180,534,2017,0,720,899],[1033,473,2044,0,720,899],[983,477,2079,0,720,899],[1002,494,2109,0,720,899],[917,488,2139,0,720,899],[917,488,2165,0,720,899],[961,483,2197,0,720,899],[897,483,2235,0,720,899],[884,498,2259,0,720,899],[826,492,2291,0,720,899],[792,483,2324,0,720,899],[774,468,2363,0,720,899],[850,469,2393,0,720,899],[803,446,2421,0,720,899],[698,426,2454,0,720,899],[701,427,2488,0,720,899],[708,449,2521,0,720,899],[672,424,2559,0,720,899],[647,439,2583,0,720,899],[616,435,2616,0,720,899],[630,438,2642,0,720,899],[664,428,2676,0,720,899],[632,428,2714,0,720,899],[664,434,2741,0,720,899],[658,428,2772,0,720,899],[658,428,2800,0,720,899],[709,423,2834,0,720,899],[709,423,2870,0,720,899],[723,405,2897,0,720,899],[660,408,2936,0,720,899],[646,414,2959,0,720,899],[619,429,2997,0,720,899]]

# Take the first two values of each array and subtract them by 100
for i in range(len(array1)):
    array1[i][0] -= 500
    array1[i][1] -= 100


combined_array = np.array(array1)

# draw the gaze_fixation.png onto saliency_map
saliency_map = cv2.imread('gaze_fixation.png', 0)

# Loop through the combined array and draw circles on the empty array
for i in range(len(combined_array)):
    x, y, duration, _, _, _ = combined_array[i]
    radius = int(duration / 80)  # Adjust the radius based on the duration
    brightness = duration / 100  # Adjust the brightness based on the duration
    saliency_map = cv2.circle(saliency_map, (x, y), radius, brightness, -1)

# Apply a Gaussian blur to the resulting array
# saliency_map = cv2.GaussianBlur(saliency_map, (0, 0), sigmaX=40, sigmaY=40)

# set the plot area to the dimenisons of the image
plt.axis([0, width, height, 0])

# Plot the resulting array
plt.imshow(saliency_map, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```